# Python fold indices for an outer cross-validation

Tags: python, pandas, cross-validation

I have a pandas dataframe `df` containing data from 2 classes. 
I would like to have randomly generated indices for a stratified K-fold cross-validation.

What I do at the moment is:

```
df_folds = np.array_split(df, 5)
for k in range(5):
    # We use 'list' to copy, in order to 'pop' later on
    df_train = list(df_folds)
    df_test  = df_train.pop(k)
    df_train = pd.concat(df_train)
```

However, this is not a stratified 5-fold cross-validation as it just splits the dataframe in 5.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
skf.get_n_splits(df)

print(skf)  

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(df):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

TypeError: split() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: sklearn already provides this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html have you tried this?

Comment: I couldn't make it work with a pandas dataframe

Comment: Please show the erroneous code in your question as sklearn is compatible with pandas dataframes

Comment: @EdChum please see the code that I tried

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38250710/2336654

Comment: Error is clear the docs show it takes 2 args, you need to pass the columns that contain the data, and then the column that contains the class label: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html