# Pandas shows SettingWithCopyWarning after train_test_split

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to manipulate a dataframe that I received from Sci-Kit Learn's *train_test_split* operation. The system gives me the following:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:179:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame

The following raises the warning on my system:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X=pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,5,7,8,9],'B':[2,5,3,51,5]})
(Xt,Xv)=train_test_split(X)
Xt.iloc[0,0]=6
```

I use the following versions:

python: '3.6.1 (default, Jun 26 2017, 19:29:26) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'

pandas: 0.20.3

sklearn: 0.18.2

Answer (score 8):

You can workaround it as follows:

```
In [16]: Xt = Xt.copy()

In [17]: Xt.iloc[0,0]=6

In [18]: Xt
Out[18]:
   A  B
0  6  2
2  7  3
1  5  5

In [19]: X
Out[19]:
   A   B
0  2   2     # <--- NOTE: the value in the original DF has NOT been changed
1  5   5
2  7   3
3  8  51
4  9   5
```

Alternatively you can use [numpy.split(...) method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251213/5741205)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. But it seems very cumbersome and inefficient to copy all output variables of train_test_split after every usage. I guess I can wrap every call like so 'map(lambda x:x.copy(),train_test_split(X,y))'

Comment: @Jonathan, you may also try to use `np.split()` instead of `train_test_split` - i've added a link to the answer, containing an example...

Comment: I tested this and it also works for me. Do you know if np.split copies the data? (I assume the warning is raised for train_test_split because it doesn't copy the data but rather creates a 'view'?)

Comment: @Jonathan, i guess `np.split()` returns copies...

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to reset the is_copy flat but it seems this is a bug of the train_test_split function.

```
Xt.is_copy=None
```

Comment: Should I post something on a sci-kit learn or pandas bug list?

Comment: I think that function is part of sci-kit learn.

Comment: Why would that be the solution? And why do you think it's a bug in sklearn?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas spits out this warning too aggressively in general, you can see a good discussion here:
[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

But if I'm confident that my code works as expected, I just use:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

at the top of my file. You'll always be able to tell if you're not updating your df because whatever you thought you did won't be there.

Comment: I don't use a chained assignment

Comment: worked for me \m/ :) thanks.