# Split dataframe into testing_df and validation_df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 23000 instances, but I want to split it such that I have one df with 3000 values and another with 20000 values. I tried using `iloc`but when I do `df.iloc[:, :20000]` it produces no usable result.

Comment: you may want to check [this question + answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test)

Comment: @MaxU Dupe seems ripe enough to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `testing_df = df.iloc[:20000]`.

Think of `iloc`'s arguments as referencing `[rows, columns]`.

Using `df.iloc[:, :20000]` as you currently have returns all rows and the first 20,000 columns, which will just be a copy of `df` unless you currently have > 20,000 columns.

See also: [Selection by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#selection-by-position).

Comment: Sample might be better, it'll shuffle the data as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using scikit-learns `train_test_split` for a random sample split (using `.iloc` is just going to split along the index, this is unlikely to be a representative split between train and test).

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.random((23000, 4)), columns = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'Y'])

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 3000)
```