# How to split dataframe into two parts with all labels in categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a data frame and need to divide it into two parts i.e 80:20 or 70:30 or 60:40 but my two parts of the data frame should have all the labels in categorical columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

```
Eg:
    Fruits  Color   Price
0   Banana  Yellow  60
1   Grape   Black   100
2   Apple   Red     200
3   Papaya  Yellow  50
4   Dragon  Pink    150
5   Mango   Yellow  400
6   Banana  Yellow  75
7   Grape   Black   106
8   Apple   Red     190
9   Papaya  Yellow  60
10  Dragon  Pink    120
11  Mango   Yellow  390

Expected 50:50 split:

df1:

3   Papaya  Yellow  50
4   Dragon  Pink    150
5   Mango   Yellow  400
6   Banana  Yellow  75
7   Grape   Black   106
8   Apple   Red     190

df2:
0   Banana  Yellow  60
1   Grape   Black   100
2   Apple   Red     200
9   Papaya  Yellow  60
10  Dragon  Pink    120
11  Mango   Yellow  390


df1,df2 = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
```

I used the above sklearn method is there any efficient way to split it so that don't miss the labels. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

with a stratified split you can make sure that the results splits are similar with respect to something. In your case it would be with respect to the labels.

The sklearn train test split functions allows to pass a stratify vector. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html
Assuming `fruits` are your labels you would need to first encode them:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
fruit_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Fruits'])
df.drop(columns='Fruits',inplace='True') # remove label from features
```

and then you can split the data like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_frame, fruit_labels,
                                                    stratify=fruit_labels, 
                                                    test_size=0.5)
```