# How to divide a dataframe into several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to divide a large data frame having multiple categorical columns with multiple labels or classes in it.

For example, I'm having **1million rows with 100 columns** and 50 columns having categorical data with different labels in it.

Now how to divide the **data frame into 2 or 3 parts(or subsets)** in which all labels in categorical columns should be present in the **2 or 3 subsets**. Is it possible to do that for large datasets?

```
def rec():
    print('#rec Started')
    shuf_data = df.sample(frac=1)
    ran_data = np.random.rand(len(shuf_data)) < 0.5
    p_d = shuf_data[ran_data]
    d = shuf_data[~ran_data]

    def rrec(p_d,d):
        print('#rrec Started')
        for col in df_cat_cols:
            p_dcol = p_d[col].unique()
            dcol = d[col].unique()
            outcome = all(elem in p_dcol for elem in dcol)
            if outcome:
                print("Yes, list1 contains all elements in list2")
            else:
                print("No, list1 does not contains all elements in list2")
                return rec()
        return p_d,d

    return rrec(p_d,d)
```

The above code **kills the process due to a very large dataset(1Million records)**. Please suggest a better and efficient answer. Thank You.

Here is an example:

```
Eg:
    Fruits  Color   Price
0   Banana  Yellow  60
1   Grape   Black   100
2   Apple   Red     200
3   Papaya  Yellow  50
4   Dragon  Pink    150
5   Mango   Yellow  400
6   Banana  Yellow  75
7   Grape   Black   106
8   Apple   Red     190
9   Papaya  Yellow  60
10  Dragon  Pink    120
11  Mango   Yellow  390

Expected 50:50 split:

df1:

3   Papaya  Yellow  50
4   Dragon  Pink    150
5   Mango   Yellow  400
6   Banana  Yellow  75
7   Grape   Black   106
8   Apple   Red     190

df2:
0   Banana  Yellow  60
1   Grape   Black   100
2   Apple   Red     200
9   Papaya  Yellow  60
10  Dragon  Pink    120
11  Mango   Yellow  390
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @rpanai, do you want an example?

Comment: Yes I do. Please have a look at [ask] too.

Comment: Hi @rpanai, I added example can you please check it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one way is to enumerate all rows with the same categories:

```
cat_cols = ['cat_col1', 'cat_col2']

groups = df.groupby(cat_cols).cumcount() // 3

sub_df = {g: d for g,d in df.groupby(groups)}
```

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang, how to assign two different dataframes to variables so that I can save.

Comment: You already have it. You can save, for example `sub_df[0].to_csv('file0.csv')`.

Comment: when I tested with 80k samples I'm getting only 1400 records each CSV file.

Comment: I checked it and it's working. Each CSV file has all the labels but how to make two CSV files with 50:50  data or 70:30 data ...etc. I'm just waiting for this only. Please suggest me.

Comment: `train = df.groupby(cat_cols).sample(frac=.7); test = df.drop(train.idx)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't don't you try using train_test_split() method from sk-learn
And OneHotEncoder() to break the categorical columns down.
This is more of a machine learning approach, and I have used it to break the dataset with a 1million rows before, so it should work

Comment: Train/test split doesn't guarantee existing of all feature values. Although it's unlikely, but you might end up with, e.g. train having all the ones while test having all the zeros.