# pandas group by devide rows into 3 groups with conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have df like like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
user = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101','102','102','101','101','102','102','102','102','102'],'Country':['India','Japan','India','Brazil','Japan','UK','Austria','Japan','Singapore','UK','UK','UK']
                    ,'Count':[85,78,70,5,6,8,60,30,5,6,5,4]})
```

i want to sort count column and assign assign top 30% rows to group 3, then next 30% to 2 and remaining 30% to group 1. How can i do that. this is my expected output. the first 4 columns. and also see my calculations how i divided 30%,30%,40%

[image: want output]

Comment: Try `pd.cut()` (it is well-documented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first sort columns by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then `groupby` with custom function with [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and return length of each group to new row of new DataFrame:

Idea from perfect [MaxU answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251213/2901002), thank you.

---

Use for top `30-30-30`:

```
user = user.sort_values(['User','Count'], ascending=[True, False])

def f(x):
    #split to 4 groups, because 3 + 3 + 3 != 1 
    a, b, c, d = np.split(x, [int(.3*len(x)), int(.6*len(x)), int(.9*len(x))])
    return pd.Series([len(a), len(b), len(c)], index=['30','30','30'])

df = user.groupby('User').apply(f)
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
      30  30  30  sum
User                 
101    1   2   1    4
102    2   2   2    6
```

and for `30-30-40`:

```
user = user.sort_values(['User','Count'], ascending=[True, False])

def f(x):
    #split to 3 groups, because 3 + 3 + 4 == 1
    a, b, c = np.split(x, [int(.3*len(x)), int(.6*len(x))])
    return pd.Series([len(a), len(b), len(c)], index=['30','30','40'])

df = user.groupby('User').apply(f)
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)

      30  30  40  sum
User                 
101    1   2   2    5
102    2   2   3    7
```

EDIT:

Groups should be created by `list comprehension`:

```
def f(x):
    a, b, c = np.split(x.index, [int(.3*len(x)), int(.6*len(x))])
    L = [a,b,c]
    return [i for i, y in zip(range(len(L),0,-1) ,L) for j in y]

user['Groups'] = user.groupby('User')['User'].transform(f)
print (user)
   User    Country  Count  Groups
0   101      India     85       3
1   101      Japan     78       2
2   101      India     70       2
6   101    Austria     60       1
5   101         UK      8       1
7   102      Japan     30       3
4   102      Japan      6       3
9   102         UK      6       2
3   102     Brazil      5       2
8   102  Singapore      5       1
10  102         UK      5       1
11  102         UK      4       1
```

Comment: How to get group column in original dataset based on the number of rows in each group?

Comment: If you see my wanted  output there's a column name group.

Comment: @KumarAK How about being polite instead of demanding? Jezrael is a volunteer who offered you his spare time and expertise. Instead of saying thank you first, you only complain.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support jezrael

Comment: @Mr.T sorry..I will remember this.

Comment: @KumarAK - Not easy, I dont add to solution, because wrongly think it is in source data :)

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the response..means it&#39;s difficult to split or the datframe by number of rows in each user? How about split the dataframe into each user wise then split the assign group based on the number of rows?

Comment: @KumarAK - added solution for groups.