# Split data into train, test, validation with stratifying using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I've just seen this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test/38251213#38251213) which shows how to split data using numpy.

Assume we're going to split them as `0.8`, `0.1`, `0.1` for training, testing, and validation respectively, you do it this way:

```
train, test, val = np.split(df, [int(.8 * len(df)), int(.9 * len(df))])
```

I'm interested to know how could I consider stratifying while splitting data using this methodology.

> Stratifying is splitting data while keeping the priors of each class you have in data. That is if you're going to take `0.8` for the training set, you take 0.8 **from each class you have**. Same for test and train.

I tried grouping the data first by class using:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(class_col_name, group_keys=False)
```

But it did not show correct results.

---

*Note: I'm familiar with `train_test_split`*

Comment: Seems you need *[Stratified sampling][1]* 
  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling

Comment: Yes. However, the question is how do we achieve it using the above approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use your groupby object, *grouped_df*, which consists of each subsetted data frame where you can then run the needed `np.split`. Then concatenate all sampled data frames with `pd.concat`. Atogether, this would *stratify* according to your quoted message:

```
train_list = []; test_list = [], val_list = []
grouped_df = df.groupby(class_col_name)

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH SUBSET DF
for i, g in grouped_df:
    # STRATIFY THE g (CLASS) DATA FRAME
    train, test, val = np.split(g, [int(.8 * len(g)), int(.9 * len(g))])

    train_list.append(train); test_list.append(test); val_list.append(val)

final_train = pd.concat(train_list)
final_test = pd.concat(test_list)
final_val = pd.concat(val_list)
```

Alternatively, a short-hand version using list comprehensions:

```
# LIST OF ARRAYS
arr_list = [np.split(g, [int(.8 * len(g)), int(.9 * len(g))]) for i, g in grouped_df]

final_train = pd.concat([t[0] for t in arr_list])
final_test = pd.concat([t[1] for t in arr_list])
final_val = pd.concat([v[2] for v in arr_list])
```

Comment: Thanks for that:), do you have any idea how can we optimize your snippet to its extreme?

Comment: Great to hear. I cannot immediately see any room for optimization. We avoid growing data frames in a loop. See edit for a more compact version but not likely any better performance.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have done stratification already such that a "category" column indicates which stratification each entry belongs to.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Dataset = namedtuple('Dataset', 'train test val')

grouped = df.groupby('headline')
splitted = {x: grouped.get_group(x).sample(frac=1) for x in grouped.groups}
datasets = {k:Dataset(*np.split(df, [int(.8 * len(df)), int(.9 * len(df))])) for k, df in splitted.items()}
```

This stores each stratified split by the category name assigned in `df`.

Each item in datasets is a `Dataset` namedtuple such that training, testing, and validation subsets are accessible by `.train`, `.test`, and `.val` respectively.