# How to stratify the training and testing data in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying to implement Classification algorithm for Iris Dataset (Downloaded from Kaggle). In the Species column the classes (Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor , Iris-virginica) are in sorted order. How can I stratify the train and test data using Scikit-Learn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split data into 3 sets (train, validation and test)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to shuffle and split your data with 0.3 test ratio, you can use

```
sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)
```

where X is your data, y is corresponding labels, **test_size** is the percentage of the data that should be held over for testing, **shuffle=True** shuffles the data before splitting

In order to make sure that the data is equally splitted according to a column, you can give it to the **stratify** parameter.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
                                                    shuffle=True, 
                                stratify = X['YOUR_COLUMN_LABEL'])
```

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that the three classes are represented equally in your train and test, you can use the **stratify** parameter of the **train_test_split** function.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, stratify = y)
```

This will make sure that the ratio of all the classes is maintained equally.

Answer (score -1):

use **sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split** and play around with **Shuffle** parameter.

**shuffle**: boolean, optional (default=True)
Whether or not to shuffle the data before splitting. If shuffle=False then stratify must be None.

Comment: Shuffle does not equally split the training and test data based on the target. Thanks though!