# How to split dataset to train, test and valid in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a dataset like this

```
my_data= [['Manchester', '23', '80', 'CM',
  'Manchester', '22', '79', 'RM',
  'Manchester', '19', '76', 'LB'],
 ['Benfica', '26', '77', 'CF',
  'Benfica', '22', '74', 'CDM',
  'Benfica', '17', '70', 'RB'],
 ['Dortmund', '24', '75', 'CM',
  'Dortmund', '18', '74', 'AM',
  'Dortmund', '16', '69', 'LM']
]
```

I know that using train_test_split from sklearn.cross_validation, and I've tried with this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(my_data, test_size = 0.2)
```

The result just split into test and train. I wish to divide it to 3 separate sets with randomized data.

Expected:
**Test, Train, Valid**

Comment: `train_test_split` divides your data into train and validation set. Don't get confused by the names. `Test` data should be where you don't know your output variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use train_test split twice

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 
    = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

 X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val 
    = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
```

also, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test/38251213#38251213)

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved using numpy+pandas, see script below splitting `0.6 + 0.2 + 0.2`:

```
train_size = 0.6
validate_size = 0.2
train, validate, test = np.split(my_data.sample(frac=1), [int(train_size * len(my_data)), int((validate_size + train_size) * len(my_data))])
```

Comment: i got error 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

Comment: my_data should be a pandas DataFrame.