# Splitting train test and validation by code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on an image dataset that has 12 classes.
Therefore, I have split the dataset manually (by hand) into three subfolders i.e. train, valid, and test in `70%, 15%,` and `15%` respectively. However, I want to split them by code for train, valid, and test `70%, 15%,` and `15%` and transfer them to the subfolder in a train, valid, and test folder

```
#--------------------------------------------------Train--------------------------------
train = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255, rotation_range=90, width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
                        horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

train_data = train_generator.flow_from_directory(directory="/content/dataset/train",target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE , color_mode="rgb" , class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE , shuffle = True )

#--------------------------------------------------valid-------------------------------
valid = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_data = validation_generator.flow_from_directory(directory="/content/dataset/validation", target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE , color_mode="rgb" , class_mode='categorical' , batch_size=BATCH_SIZE , shuffle = True )

#--------------------------------------------------Test---------------------------------------------
test = ImageDataGenerator()
test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_data = test_generator.flow_from_directory(directory="/content/dataset/test",target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE , color_mode="rgb" , class_mode='categorical' , batch_size=1 , shuffle = False )
test_data.reset()
```

It is possible to write the code for spiting them send it to the 3 several folders?

Comment: I think this question has answers your are looking for. From there you can save the variables to a file if you wish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test

Comment: In Tensorflow, use `tfds.Split` to split the dataset into train, test and validation dataset.For more information on the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/Split). Thanks!