# Split and Normalize Data for Each State(Covid 19

Tags: python

Can someone help me, I have COVID-19 data for the US and it has data for all states based and I separated in 55 data frames (for 55 states).

Problem 1: I want to split all 55 data frame to Train/Test/val(80/10/10).

Code for splitting 55 states data is below: I used Pandas

```py
Uniq_Provinces = Covid19.Province_State.unique()

dataframes = []

for filename in Uniq_Provinces:

   df =  pd.DataFrame(Covid19[Covid19['Province_State'] == filename])

   dataframes.append(df)
```

Can you please help as I am not so good at writing python code as well as how to finally merge all training, test and val again

Comment: Uniq_Provinces = Covid19.Province_State.unique()

dataframes = []
for filename in Uniq_Provinces:
   df =  pd.DataFrame(Covid19[Covid19['Province_State'] == filename])
   dataframes.append(df)

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split data into 3 sets (train, validation and test)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test)