# Split a text file into multiple files by percentage for test and train

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large txt file with 50000+ line, how can I randomly split them into 70% for training, 20% for test, and 10% for dev.

result expecting :
train.txt, test.txt, dev.txt

Answer (score 3):

I found this code much simpler.

```
## allocating train, test and validate datasets
import random 

fin = open('unique.txt', 'rb') 
f75out = open("train.txt", 'wb') 
f125aout = open("test.txt", 'wb')
f125bout = open("validate.txt", 'wb')

for line in fin: 
  r = random.random() 
  if (0.0 <=  r <= 0.75): 
    f75out.write(line) 
  elif (0.75 < r <= 0.875): 
    f125aout.write(line) 
  else:
    f125bout.write(line)
fin.close() 
f75out.close() 
f125aout.close() 
f125bout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Scikit Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)'s method *train_test_split()* to split your training data in subsets.

Then just save your variables in files.

Comment: so, will be ``` data = 'file.txt'   train,test,dev = train_test_split(data,train_size=0.8, test_size=0.1, dev_size=0.1) ```  is that correct?

Comment: You would actually use train_test_split() twice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932524/16744221