# How to split dataframe randomly into given ratio according id

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns. How can I split according column "id" in a 70/30 ratio randomly.
So with id 7 despite 3 occurring values ​​it only counts as 1/10 with ratio.

[How to split data into 3 sets (train, validation and test)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test) Does not help in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9,10,10], 'col2': [3,4,5,7,8,9,1,5,9,10,11,4,1,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So possible output df1_30 would be:

```
>>> df1_30
     id   col2
0    1    3
2    3    5
3    3    7
11   9    4
```

Another possible output of df1_30 could be also (just for clarification):

```
>>> df1_30
     id   col2
0    1    3
10   8    11
11   9    4
```

Comment: what if output_df1_30 is id=3 3 7 7 7 9, This is possible right ..?

Comment: yes would be also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully below code will help you , len_per is 30 percentage of total unique ids you have

```
 import pandas as pd
 import random
 d = {'id': [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9,10,10], 'col2': [3,4,5,7,8,9,1,5,9,10,11,4,1,7]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 len_per = int(len(set(df['id'])) / 100 * 30)
 ids = random.sample(set(df["id"]), len_per)

 df1_30 = df[df["id"].isin(ids)]
 df1_70 = df[~df["id"].isin(ids)]
```

OutPut

```
   id   col2
1   2   4
5   5   9
11  9   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems it works. In fact my data is quite large. I have to check the computional costs. What would be an elegant solution to receive df1_70 with the other 70 percent?

Comment: @qwertzi, Updated the code with df1_70 `~` is used to get exact same outcome as `!` in `pandas`

Comment: Okay very fast^^. Thanks (and also for explanation).

Comment: @qwertzi Welcome bro,and pleas accept the answer , and one more thing just update 3 with `len_per` variable in `random.sample()`, already updated the code

Comment: It also works for a large dataset like charm. N1!