# Best practice for train, validation and test set

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I want to assign a sample class to each instance in a dataframe - 'train', 'validation' and 'test'. If I use sklearn train_test_split(), twice, I can get the indices for a train, validation and test set like this:

```
X = df.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y=df[['target']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, indices_train, indices_test=train_test_split(X, y, df.index, 
                                                                             test_size=0.2, 
                                                                             random_state=10, 
                                                                             stratify=y, 
                                                                             shuffle=True)
df_=df.iloc[indices_train]

X_ = df_.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y_=df_[['target']]

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, indices_train, indices_val=train_test_split(X_, y_, df_.index, 
                                                                             test_size=0.15, 
                                                                             random_state=10, 
                                                                             stratify=y_, 
                                                                             shuffle=True)

df['sample']=['train' if i in indices_train else 'test' if i in indices_test else 'val' for i in df.index]
```

What is best practice to get a train, validation and test set? Is there any problems with my approach above and can it be frased better?

Comment: You are splitting in the wrong way your data. Give me a couple of minutes to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did a dummy dataset of 100 points.
I separate the data and I did the first split:

```
X = df.drop('target', axis=1)
y = df['target']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
```

If you have a look, my test size is 0.3 which means 70 data points will go for traininf and 30 for **test and validation** as well.

```
X_train.shape # Output (70, 3)
X_test.shape # Output (30, 3)
```

Now you need to split again for validation, so you can do it like this:

```
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5)
```

Notice how I name the groups and the **test_size is now 0.5**. Which means I take the 30 points for test and I splitted for validation as well. So the shape of validation and testing, will be:

```
X_val.shape # Output (15, 3)
X_test.shape # Output (15, 3)
```

At the end you have 70 points for training, 15 for testing and 15 for validation.
Now, consider validation as "double check" of your training. There are a lot of messy concepts related with that. It's just be sure of your training.

Comment: Thanks. It looks quite similar to my approach, except for the size of the splits. Is it important that the validation and test size are the same size you recon?

Comment: Up to you. But in my opinion, it's best approach go for cross-validation. You avoid things like overfitting with that. But if your dataset is huge, go for train test split.

Comment: :) Thanks for input. Do you mean I don't need a validation set if my dataset is huge?

Comment: Cross-validation will take forever. In that case, go for train-test-split.

Comment: Oh yes, you right. However, I need a validation set for XGBoost, even if it will take forever :)

Comment: It really doesn't matter too much the validation set. As I said, this is like a "double check of your training", so if you can go with cross-validation, you will get a better training.

Answer (score 2):

a faster and optimal solution if dataset is large would be using numpy.

[How to split data into 3 sets (train, validation and test)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test/38251213#38251213)

or the simpler way is your solution, but maybe just feed the x_train, y_train you obtained in the 1 step, for the train validation split? like the indices being stored and rows just removed from the df feels unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The indices are important to be able to create the feature 'sample' in the original dataframe.

Comment: is it necessary to store which record went in which set using that sample class? wont it be simple to store your 3 sets separately and then just access them when required. Like why manipulate the source data. I am curious now xD

Comment: It's not necessary, it just want I want. Your way is fine aswell. I have no argument aginst that. :)